# jQuery Remove attribute in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax call that I disable a checkbox and I then want to enable again once the ajax has finished. However I cannt remove the attribute disabled aterwards.

```
$(function(){ // added
    $("input:checkbox").live("click", function(){

        var a_href = $(this).attr('id');
        var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
        if (checked == 'checked') {
            checked = 1;
        }else {
            checked = 0
        };

        $(this).parent().parent().after('<img class="loader" style="padding-botton:0 !important;" alt="" src="images/loaders/loader.gif">');
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/featured.php",
            data: { id: a_href, value: checked, field: "main_feature" },
          success: function(data) {
            $('img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); 
          }             
        }).done(function (data){
            }
        );

    return false; 


    });
}); // added
```

I have also tried:

```
.attr('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to save a reference to `this` because `this` inside ajax callback is the ajax request.

```
$("input:checkbox").live("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    ...
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        $('img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $this.removeAttr('disabled');
```

or set the `context` to `this`:

```
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        context: this, // <===============
        url: "includes/featured.php",
        data: { id: a_href, value: checked, field: "main_feature" },
      success: function(data) {
          // Now this is the checkbox!
        $('img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled'); 
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

`this` in the AJAX success handler will not be the checkbox. You'll need to cache that variable first, then you can use it in the success handler. It's also worth noting that it's better to use `prop` or `removeProp` when removing attributes. Try this:

```
$(function(){ // added
    $("input:checkbox").live("click", function(){
        var $checkbox = $(this);

        var a_href = $checkbox.attr('id');
        var checked = $checkbox.attr('checked');
        checked = (checked == "checked") ? 1 : 0;

        $checkbox.parent().parent().after('<img class="loader" style="padding-botton:0 !important;" alt="" src="images/loaders/loader.gif">');
        $checkbox.attr('disabled','disabled');

        $.ajax( {
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/featured.php",
            data: { id: a_href, value: checked, field: "main_feature" },
            success: function(data) {
                $('img.loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $checkbox.removeProp('disabled'); 
            }             
        }).done(function (data) {});

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 'this' inside the success function is what you think it is. Try setting a variable outside the ajax scope for your checkbox, and then referencing that inside the success function.

Comment: is right `$(this).removeAttr('disabled'); ` this doesnt refer to the checkbox anymore..you'd have to say something like... `$('#checkbox1').removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score 2):

Your `$(this)` is out of scope when you try to re-enable your checkbox.

Add `var newthis = $(this)` after

`$("input:checkbox").live("click", function(){`

and change your call to remove the 'disabled' attr to

`newthis.removeAttr('disabled');`